# Is it because I am in a different time zone to the server or does everone see 2 hours, 2 minutes after commenting?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow, comments

I have answered a couple of questions today but have noticed that it says I posted that answer 2 hours ago, while 2 minutes have passed. I'm in Africa and I heard Africa is usually 2 hours behind, so I am just wondering if everyone is also seeing "2 hours ago" instead of "2 minutes ago" after posting an answer. Or could it possible be a small bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the time for Stack Exchange is UTC (Universal Time). You can see it by mousing over your username in the top bar.

You probably see the two hour difference because of some time zone setting that is not correct on your computer, or something like that.

Comment: Oh... Yeah... Man. My linux is 2 hours ahead of my windows OS and my windows OS has the correct time. Thanks. **dumb of me**. Guess you got to wait 9 minutes before I can accept your answer. :-)